# why is this Markov Chain aperiodic

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have this Matrix:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ 0.3 & 0.7 \end{pmatrix}$$

this markov chain is said to be aperiodic, I dont understand how it comes to it. Period $\delta$ is the gcd of the set of all diagonal elements, right? if $\delta>1$, $P$ is periodic, if $\delta=1$, then aperiodic.

but here it is not $\delta=1$, is it? or do i have to transit the matrix to some certain form?

Comment: There's a stationary state $(1,0)$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, what does it tell me? can you please explain in more words

Comment: When there's a stationary state, your system will evolve towards that state. In your case, the two left eigenvectors are $(-1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ with corresponding eigenvalues $-0.3$ and $1$. Every other state of the system can be decomposed into those two states. The first state exihibits oscillating behaviour, but it dies out as $0.3<1$. The other state is stationary. So whatever your initial state, you'll evolve towards that stationary state.

Comment: @raskolnikov, oh okay. thanks a lot. this gave me more push to study more ;)

Comment: doniyor: As already mentioned two weeks ago, the accepted answer is wrong. Dunno if this interests you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment provided sufficient clarification:

When there's a stationary state, your system will evolve towards that state. In your case, the two left eigenvectors are $(−1,1)$ and $(3,10)$ with corresponding eigenvalues $−0.3$ and $1$. Every other state of the system can be decomposed into those two states. The first state exihibits oscillating behaviour, but it dies out as $0.3<1$. The other state is stationary. So whatever your initial state, you'll evolve towards that stationary state.

Comment: great, thanks in tons

Comment: I fail to understand this answer. The state (1,0) is not stationary and no state "dies out". doniyor: can you explain what you understood?

Comment: I guess I replied as a physicist rather than as a mathematician. $(1,0)$ and $(-1,1)$ are linearly independent left eigenvectors. They thus form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Every other state can be decomposed into a linear combination of those two states in a unique way. But if one looks at the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x,y)P^n$, then one will always get a multiple of $(1,0)$ as a result.

Comment: Even more than others, a *pĥysicist* should be wary not to declare that state 1 (represented by vector (1,0)) is a stationary state for a process which bounces forever between states 1 and 2, spending 3 thirteenths of its time in state 1 and the rest in state 2. (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did: I'm not sure what you're going on about. [It's a text book definition really.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions)

Comment: And you sincerely believe that $\pi=(1,0)$ solves the system given in the "textbook definition"? Sorry but it does not, only $\pi=(\frac3{13},\frac{10}{13})$ does.

Comment: @Did: Ah, now I see what you mean. I must have been squinting or something. :D

Answer (score 2):

Call the states $a$ and $b$. The chain is irreducible since $P(a,b)=1\ne0$ and $P(b,a)=0.3\ne0$. One can go from $b$ to $b$ with positive probability in one step (probability $0.7$) hence the period of $b$ is $1$.  The chain is irreducible hence the period of every state is $1$ (this can also be proved directly). That is, the chain is aperiodic.

Answer (score 1):

Intutive answer;

the markov chain is aperiodic since it is reached from any node to itself in not periodic interval e.g 2, 4, 6,......

here the P11 makes it as a aperiodic since the chain re goes to node after 2,3,5 e.g no periodicity

Answer (score 1):

Since the [Jordan Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0.3&0.7
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0.3&0.7
\end{bmatrix}^n
&=\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.3&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-10&3\\3&3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
&=\frac1{13}\begin{bmatrix}
3&10\\3&10
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the initial state $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ tends toward the fixed point state
$$
\left(\frac3{13}x+\frac{10}{13}y\right)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$